# Redirect direct image access

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Im struggling with this problem and i know there are some solutions but none is working fine for me. I want to redirect direct image access to its HTML site because the image filename is exact the same like the HTML site. Example:

```
http://example.com/images/subcategory/this-is-an-image.png
```

should be redirected to

```
http://example.com/images/subcategory/this-is-an-image.html
```

The image can be an png, jpg, jpeg or gif. And of course i still want to embedd the images in `<img>` tags on my site. The goal is not to prevent hotlinking, the goal is to redirect all direct image calls on my server to its html site. Are there any solutions? Thank you.

Comment: how will you determine between someone loading the image directly, v.s. someone loading the img because it HAS been hotlinked (from your html or from elsewhere)? There's no 100% reliable method to do this, and referers can NOT be trusted.

Comment: if the method also prevents hotlinking its ok, i just wanted to clearify, that preventing hotlinging is not the main goal.

Comment: yeah, but you're redirecting ALL access to the image to a .html file, so anything that's legitimately got `<img src="/images/subcategory/this-is-an-image.png">` is going to sucking in the redirect html as the image data, and just show a broken image icon. like I said, hotlink detection is NOT 100% reliable, and you're going to be forcing people to suck down html instead of .png data in a large fraction of your user base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ $1.html [NC,R,L]
```

Not 100% reliable method, but better than nothing...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now all embedded images are broken but the direct image access is still working.

Comment: You have correctly replaced "example" with your actual domain name ?

Comment: It's not for direct image access, but for access from other website. You can delete `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$`. for that.

Comment: Ah, thank you. This is working now! But the strange behavior now: i can enter the image url and the image is displayed. If i press F5 i get redirected to the html site. Any ideas? Could this be a cache problem because is testes a bit too much with this url?

Comment: Yes, try with other browser.

Comment: Symfony cache clear, browser cache clear and its working. Thank you mate!

Comment: @Croises can you please help me with similar question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241563/prevent-direct-images-access-but-allow-embedding